# local minima and global minima in quadratic programming

Tags: analysis

The problem is as follows:
Let $Q∈R^{dxd}$ and $A∈R^{d′xd}$  be two matrixes and $b∈Rd$, ^$c∈R^d′$. Suppose $d′<d$.For $x∈R^d$.

Minimize
$f(x)=1/2x^TQx−b^Tx$ subject to $Ax=c$

Prove that all local minima are global minima. Convexity is not supposed (H not necessarily possitive definite.)

What I did so far is:

If there is any feasible point $x^{(0)}$ all feasible points are of the form ${x^{(0)}+Z\cdot y}$ where $Z\in Ker(A)$
$f(x)=g(y)=1/2y^TZ^THZy-u^Ty$.
However how can I finish the prove that all local minima of g(y) is global minima?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: All negative directions of $H$ most lie in the range of $A$.

EDIT:

The only way $g(y)$ can have a minimum (that isn't just $-\infty$) is if $Z^THZ$ is positive semi-definite (PSD).You can prove this by contradiction. Say that $Z^THZ$ is not PSD. Then you could let $y$ move in the negative directions of $Z^THZ$ and make $g(y)$ arbitrarily small. Thus the only way for $g(y)$ to have a finite minimum is if $Z^THZ$ is PSD, which also implies that any local minimum is also a global one.

Comment: I had the intuition that this should be as you said, that's why I took the prove untill that point, but i dont know how to continue. Can you plz give me a proof?